# PeerJS 'on' is not defined

Tags: reactjs, next.js, webrtc, peerjs

Im trying to connect to users with Web RTC peerjs. I want to be able to directly set the id instead of peerjs automatically setting a random one.

**This works:**

```js
useEffect(() => {

  const peer = new Peer();
  peer.on("open", (id) => {
    console.log(id);
  })
}, [])
```

**But when I try to set the id manually like this:**

```js
useEffect(() => {
  //setting an id myself like this:
  const peer = new Peer("set-id-873923");
  
  peer.on("open", (id) => {
    console.log(id);
  })
}, [])
```

I get this error in another function which in I try to access the peer variable (which is in a useRef). Which ONLY happens when I set an ID myself.

Here is the code for that

```
const call = (remotePeerId) => {
var getUserMedia =
  navigator.getUserMedia ||
  navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
  navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true }, (mediaStream) => {
  currentUserVideoRef.current.srcObject = mediaStream;
  currentUserVideoRef.current.play();

  const call = peerInstance.current.call(remotePeerId, mediaStream);

  call.on("stream", (remoteStream) => {
    remoteVideoRef.current.srcObject = remoteStream;
    remoteVideoRef.current.play();
  });
});
```

};

"**Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')**"

Comment: should you maybe use `peer.current.on` as it is stored in a ref?

Comment: @VivaanKumar try to take `peer` instance outside the `hook` and create a `func` where you can `directly set the id` and call this `func` inside the `hook`

Comment: Please provide a [mre].